# Fill in the linear layout three items

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-imageview

I have a little problem. My problem is about fill in the blanks. I try everything but I dont really understand. And now please help me?

How fill three items in linear layout? And, How fill auto width?

I give a screenshoot. I have three social button. But not put in layout fill.

[image]

Code:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
  android:background="@color/ColorPrimary">

  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:background="#00aced">

    <ImageView
      android:layout_width="38dp"
      android:layout_height="38dp"
      android:src="@drawable/twitter"
      android:id="@+id/imageView2"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:background="#125688">

    <ImageView
      android:layout_width="38dp"
      android:layout_height="38dp"
      android:src="@drawable/instagram"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="131dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:background="#3b5998">

    <ImageView
      android:layout_width="38dp"
      android:layout_height="38dp"
      android:src="@drawable/facebook"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

  </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Why are you using **3** LinearLayouts? **1** is more than enough. Use weights on the ImageViews.

Comment: But fill in the blanks. Because I need auto width.

Comment: You need **weights**. That way your ImageViews will all take `33.333%` of the width. But set the container to orientation="horizontal"

Comment: I dont understand? Why use imageviews?

Comment: OK. Good night. Sleep well.

Comment: Ok, sorry I see this comment. I'll try this.

Comment: What did you *want* it to look like, approximately? (A bad drawing of the intended layout would be helpful here.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below Code

Removed unwanted code. in such scenarios always use `Linear Layout` and `layout_wieght`

and also try studying about various `Layouts` in Android

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
                android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight ="1"
                        android:layout_height="38dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/twitter"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight ="1"
                        android:layout_height="38dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/instagram"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight ="1"
                        android:layout_height="38dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/facebook"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

                </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for support. Very awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You could use an horizontal **LinearLayout** instead of an **FrameLayout** and set the **layout_weight** property from all three **ImageViews** to "1", so they'll fill all possible space.

Don't forget to remove all unnecessary **LinearLayouts**.